# Model comparison using lower bound from variational approximation

Tags: probit, model-comparison, variational-bayes

I applied variational approximation for probit regression model and got the lower bound for the log marginal likelihood. When I compare models with different covariates using lower bound, I found that the lower bound always prefer the simpler model. Is there any way to add correction to the lower bound so that different model can be comparable?

Comment: Which type of variational approximation did you use? Although there are some common approximations, this information may make it easier to answer your question about how to improve the lower bound.